# Does anyone know what this type of furnace/heater is called?

Tags: furnace, heater, antique

I have this old style of heating but I cannot find any information on it. Can anyone help? It's gas and just sorta gets hot heating the house. No blower, no ducts, just the exhaust. The brand on the front says Quaker. It's old.

[image]

Comment: `space heater` or `room heater`

Comment: That type gets its combustion air from the living space and sends its exhaust gasses to the living space. If you use it, you must crack a window or otherwise let in outside air. If there is no, or insufficient, fresh air coming in, then the exhaust will contain carbon monoxide, which is deadly toxic. Even if there is fresh air coming into the living space a maladjusted burner mixer can lead to production of carbon monoxide.  Modern heaters get combustion air through a tube from outside and send exhaust gasses out another flue.

Answer (score 2):

It is a free standing stove or room heater that was used in homes before people installed forced air heating systems. They were used in homes where I lived growing up in the 1950's. We had 1 in our home and it heated (sort of) 3 rooms with the help of small electric fans.

Comment: @Jim, the 1 we had, had a flue pipe on the back that collected the flue gases and directed them through a flue pipe to a chimney. Ours was made by a company called "Moore". The room that had the heater was warm and the other 2 were just just OK. The one in the picture looks similar to the one we had.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a Quaker Manufacturing convection stove and I did not know they made one in gas. They did a lot of oil and kerosene. It's probably not the safest way to heat and definitely not very efficient. There may have several companies making heaters with Quaker in the name so it will hard to identify it. Just so you know, it's not certified for use. If it caused a fire your insurance company would deny your claim.